# Reactjs - grid on the screen

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and as a small project I want to create a simple game where there will be a grid (just like a chess board) and the user will be clicking on particular squares changing their colours.

Now my question is, before I start the actual codes, what should I do the grid with (eg. canvas, svg, divs with borders)or yet some other way?

I just don't want to start coding and after a few hours I'll find out that that was a completely wrong direction.

Thank you

Comment: Divs will be the easiest, I say you start there. Also, if you're just starting out coding then you definitely want to get comfortable with the idea of rewriting a few hours of work. It's going to happen a lot and it's almost always a great learning experience.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. Would I better change the colours by adding / removing classes to divs or purely in js?

Comment: I always go with css for visual styling. It's what it's there for.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean but would I define css classes and add/remove them using js or define all css properties in js?

Comment: Classes are the way to go.